# Liferay How to add icons to top navigation bar?

Tags: navigation, icons, liferay, portal

I am trying to insert on my top navigation bar icon to go with text but i am not being able to do this. Used Custom fields but nothing works.

Comment: try using css to display icons

Comment: For example: nav ul li a {
    background : /*some image url*/ }

Comment: Do you want to add this in theam or what. Please let us know your requirement and what you have done earlier.

Comment: Thanks i resolve the problem, the problem was that the user insert the menus dynamic and i didn't want to be something fixed.

Answer (score 0):

i have the same issue after searching i found this answer in [liferay website](https://web.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/31145255)  that help me

To insert icon/image in Navigation menu/bar follow the below steps.

1. Click Manage --> Page
2. Select the page that you want to upload image/icon.
3. Click Advanced link from right hand side column.
4. upload the image from Icon(This icon will be shown in the navigation menu).
5. Click save button.